# Evenly distribute wrapped text between lines in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, word-wrap, swiftui-text

How can I tell SwiftUI that when text wraps, I'd like all the lines to be as close to equal length as possible?

For example, I don't want this:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the
lazy dog
```

Even if there is enough horizontal space to fit everything except "lazy dog" on the first line, I want this instead (or whatever gives the most equal line lengths for the font in use):

```
The quick brown fox
jumps over the lazy dog
```

Comment: Can it be limited to 2 lines? Or does it need to dynamically adjust how many lines?

Comment: @aheze A general solution for as many lines as the text requires would be best, but a partial solution for text known to fit into 2 lines would still be useful.